# Highstock xAxis datetime

Tags: javascript, highcharts

I use Highstock  to display a graph showing the number of visitors in column and I need  the zoom to display the number of visitors per day, per month and per year

In my graph I can display a number of visitor per day, but I would like display a number of visitor per month and per year too. 
But when I look my graph (per month) I don't have a graph with 12 column, I have a graph with 365 column (one per day).

I use the type datetime for xAxis, but it doesn't work...

> > x rangeSelector: {
> >
> > > ```
> > >        inputDateFormat:'%d.%m.%Y',
> > >        inputEditDateFormat:'%d.%m.%Y',
> > >        buttonTheme: {
> > >            width: 80
> > >        },
> > > ```
> >
> > ```
> >        buttons: [{
> >                type: 'day',
> >                count: 7,
> >                text: 'day'
> >            }, {
> >                type: 'month',
> >                count: 12,
> >                text: 'month'
> >            }, {
> >                type: 'year',
> >                count: 1,
> >                text: 'years'
> >            }],
> >        selected: 0
> >    },
> > ```
> >
> > Axis: {
> >
> > > ```
> > >       minTickInterval: 24 * 3600 * 1000,
> > >        type: 'datetime',
> > >        title: {
> > >            text: 'Time'
> > >        },
> > >        dateTimeLabelFormats: {
> > >            day: '%d.%m<br/>%Y'
> > >       }
> > >    }
> > > ```

How can I have a graph with "a addition of the visitors per column" ?

Below is what I get now. The first graph is OK, but the second, it's not OK. I would 12 columns and not 365.

Per Days:
[image: Per Days:]
Per Years:
[image]

Answer (score 0):

Range selector buttons affecting to the time span which should be displayed on a chart. If you want to display specific unit on a chart, you need to use forced dataGrouping, see:

- http://api.highcharts.com/highstock#plotOptions.series.dataGrouping.units
- http://api.highcharts.com/highstock#plotOptions.series.dataGrouping.forced

Example could be found here: http://www.highcharts.com/stock/demo/candlestick-and-volume